# Cordova Inappbrowser loadstart event determine if the target is blank

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

Using the cordova inappbrowser `loadstart` event is there a way to determine if the link that has been clicked has the target attribute set to blank? The reason I want to do this is so that I can divert these URLs to the system browser.

I am trying to find out what properties the event parameter has. I am using `event.url` but I was hoping there would be an `event.target` which would be set to blank.

```
app.inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event) {
    alert("URL = " + event.url);
    alert("Link Target = " + event.target
});
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is an "event.target" that has a default property. I believe by default the link will open the actual in app browser instead of the device's default.

To override the default you must specify the target to be '_system':

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_system', 'location=no');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The link that I want to open in the system browser is within the web page being displayed in the inappbrowser. So I don't have control of the link from within the app. When any links on the webpage are clicked the loadstart event fires so I have the potential to intercept it and divert it to the system browser. do you know if there is a reference to find out what properties are in the event?

Comment: I don't know of a reference like that, but maybe you could store the url as a value when it is clicked, then open the url in a system value. @ee0jmt